Is encouraging aliyah to Israel a mitzvah?
Thank God we have a Jewish State. The Rambam notes the importance of living in Israel "even in a city of majority gentiles, and shouldn't live in a city outside of Israel even with a majority of Jews" (see hilchot Melachim 5:12). However, the Rambam does not count it as one of the 613 mitzvot; some have said because it is a precursor to all observance...
Rav Melamed says "This mitzvah [yishuv Eretz Yisrael] is incumbent upon the Jewish people in every generation" (see here)
Given the importance of living in Israel, are there responsa regarding the extent to which Jews need to be encouraged to live in Israel? Kiruv organizations encourage shmirat mitzvot. Are there halachic grounds to do the same thing for aliyah specifically? And to what extent would it be considered a mitzvah i.e., would it be considered under "not standing idly by" in the face of worldwide antisemitism (or other).

I don't find this question compelling since there's no reason provided to think this isn't like any other good thing to encourage people (who are capable) of doing. Why should anyone have written responsa about something obvious?

It's important to distinguish between the land of Israel and the state. The Eim Habonim Smeichah, for example, says nothing about the establishment of a state, other than to say that the early Zionists were massive reshaim. He focuses exclusively on Yishuv Eretz Yisroel.

And there are people for whom moving there right now would be disastrous given their particular marriage/kids/financial/social/mental-health/physical-health/whatever situation as of today. In those cases, it would be a significant eitzah she'einah hogenes to encourage them to leap before they look.
